# AngularJs animation for ng-show faster when showing than hiding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, transition, ng-animate, ng-show

I have an Angular (1.3.14) app (shown below) which is supposed to animate the `ng-show` when you click the link. I expect it to expand / contract at the same speed, but I cannot get it to work correctly. I also don't know why the height change is waiting until after the element has changed opacity. I would expect them to happen at the same time. Any ideas?

Here is an example of the issue I am having: https://jsfiddle.net/0wcrcwxe/

```js
    angular.module("app", ["ngAnimate"])
    .controller("WebController", ["$scope", "$q", "$timeout", function($scope, $q, $timeout) {
     this.checked = true;
    }]);
```

```css
    .animate-show {
        max-height:9999px !important;
        opacity: 1;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .animate-show.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
    .animate-show.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
        transition:all ease 3.35s;
    }
    .animate-show.ng-hide {
        max-height:0  !important;
        opacity:0;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" data-ng-app="app">
    <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body data-ng-controller="WebController as ctrl">
    
    <div>
         <a href="#" data-ng-click="ctrl.checked = !ctrl.checked">Click to show / hide</a>
         <div class="animate-show" data-ng-show="ctrl.checked">
                I show up all the time<br/>
                I show up all the time<br/>
                I show up all the time<br/>
                I show up all the time<br/>
                I show up all the time<br/>
                I show up all the time<br/>
                I show up all the time<br/>
         </div>
     </div>
    End
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-animate.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear.  I would like it to collapse and change opacity at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of the `max-height:9999px`.

When i changed the `max-height:150px` it worked as expected.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0wcrcwxe/1/

Comment: Do you know why max-height would effect this?

Comment: During the animation `max-height` changes from either `0 - 9999 or 9999 - 0 in 3.35 sec`. 
While show we need a minimum `max-height` of 150px. Changing the value from 0 to 150 will not take much time hence we are able to see the changes quickly. 
While hide Changing the value from 9999 - 150 will take much time hence we are able to see the changes slowly.

Comment: This means that max-height is only marginally better than height when it comes to transitions.